# Pros and Cons of gems from a Linux distribution vs gem install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rubygems, fedora

Linux distributions like Fedora package and maintain tons of gems as rpm packages for easy install with `yum` or now `dnf`. Even Ruby on Rails.

The question is, when making a RoR website that will use ~10 gems or so, what are the pros and cons of using the packaged gems from the Linux distribution compared to just `gem install`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) to manage Ruby gems.  Some Ruby gems depend on other gems, so your project may only use 10 gems directly, but there might be a total of 100 dependencies.  If you use a Gemfile or gemspec to list your dependencies and manage them with bundler, than another Ruby developer can pull your codebase and run `bundle install` to have all the gems with the proper versions their machine.

Comment: Linux distributions only include gems in packages so that they can be used as command-line tools easily. Trying to rely on them for use in your project will only end in sadness! Like Powers said, other developers don't want to apt-get install all your gems by hand and manually resolve conflicts... they just want to run `bundle install` and be done with it. I'm a veteran of the era before bundler was popular, and trust me, we don't want to go back to those dark times.

Answer (score 1):

> gem is the front end to RubyGems, a sophisticated package manager
>   for Ruby.

Probably, your distribution will not contain all available ruby gems.
And gems in your distribution will probably be not up-to-date.

Here an example running on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
$: sudo apt-cache show ruby-rails-4.0
=> Version: 4.0.2+dfsg-2

$ gem search "^rails$"
=> rails (4.2.3)
```

As you see, the gem of my distrubition is pretty old, whereas the gem from [rubygems](https://rubygems.org/) is up-to-date ;)

Comment: I was actually thinking this could be considered good for some, as you then would get the distributions QA.